# Error message qgis-ltr-bin.exe

Tags: error, windows

While opening the software the error message is poping up.

> The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library.api-ms-win-crt-runtime-I1-1-0.dll

Installed version is QGIS 3.10.8

Comment: The software doesn't open with the qgis-ltr-bin.exe but, but with the qgis-ltr.bat file.

Comment: how to resolve the issue.

Comment: i haved already installed the software in my system. but while opening the software  the error message is poping up.

Comment: How did you install the software? How are you opening it?

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the dll-files. https://www.dll-files.com/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll.html